# Bug in SE chat for iPhone

Tags: bug, chat, google-chrome

There is a bug in chat for iPhone (it may be classified also as SE application bug, I believe - since that application proposes to use chrome if it was installed

Under IOS 8, chrome crashes in chat page, when trying to load messages after chat tab lost the focus and later was focused again (if those messages present, of course). This never happened till IOS update. Device is iPhone 5.

Also, it may be chrome bug (?) - but standard safari works well with chat window.

Comment: Are you in the mobile theme, or full site theme?

Comment: Starting with iOS 8.1, I cannot log into chat on the iPad using Safari, but can log in with Chrome. Agh.